# Reading Files in Windows Phone 8: Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, readfile

I'm really problems when open files stored in my project. I need open some files (pdf, html,...) and ever has the same problem: **Value does not fall within the expected range**.

I have tried several ways:

a)

```
private async Task<string> ReadFileContentsAsync(string fileName)
{
    StorageFolder foldera = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

    try
    {
        Stream filea = await foldera.OpenStreamForReadAsync("/Assets/Data/htm/" + fileName + ".htm");


        ...
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("ERROR ReadFileContentsAsync " + e.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

b)

```
private async Task<string> ReadFileContentsAsync(string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(
                new Uri("ms-appdata:///Assets/Data/htm/" + fileName + ".htm", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

        ...
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("ERROR ReadFileContentsAsync " + e.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

c)

```
StorageFile file2 = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(
                                            new Uri("ms-appdata:///Assets/Data/pdf/lc_dossier_acceso_castellana.pdf", UriKind.Absolute));
```

This actions are launched when I push a button.

I don't know what's happen.

The files are in Solution'NewProject'/NewProject/Assets/Data/*/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I noticed that I get that error if I use the slash `/` in the path to the file. Instead, if I use backslash `\` I can get the files.

Try following way:

```
StorageFile sFile = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"Assets\Data\htm\" + fileName + ".htm");

var fileStream = await sFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
```

Note that you have to place an `@` before the path string to avoid the intepretation of `\` as scape character.

You could also get the file stream this way:

```
var fileStream = File.OpenRead("Assets/Data/htm/" + fileName + ".htm");
```

Comment: thanks, "var fileStream = File.OpenRead("Assets/Data/htm/" + fileName + ".htm");" works!!