# await FileIO.ReadTextAsync giving error (edited: now using IStorageFile.OpenReadAsync)

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, async-await

I have this method in my project. This is what it is supposed to do: 
It accepts a string which is the name of a file in a folder, AV, in the Assets folder of my project. It opens this file and performs some operations on it (not all of the required operations are in the code, yet).

```
    public async static Task<Book> ParseFile(string bookN)
    {
        string bookName = bookN.Replace(" ", "");

        StorageFile bookFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/AV/" + bookName + ".txt"));
        string content = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(bookFile);

        string chapterStr = "CHAPTER";

        int numOfChapters = Utilities.NumOfTimesStringOccurs(content, chapterStr);

        Book book = new Book(bookName, numOfChapters);
        //book.Chapters = new List<Chapter>(numOfChapters);

        return book;
    }
```

The problem is this line:

```
    string content = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(bookFile);
```

I know this because I set a breakpoint at the first line of the method. After stepping into the code, that particular line broke and opened the `.g.cs` file and was highlighting a line that apparently implied the compiler could not trace it. The line had to do with `diagnostics.debugger` or something like that.

The next step I tried was to put in a `try` and display the error in a `MessageDialog`. The error from this was:

```
    Object reference was not found
```

or something similar.

I am thinking it could be that the line

```
    StorageFile bookFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/AV/" + bookName + ".txt"));
```

is causing this since it has `await` so maybe the operation was not complete before the next line could be executed. But I don't expect it to be slow since the files in the folder are just 5 - 6 kB each on average.

I don't know what's wrong as this is my first time of using the `Storage` namespace classes as I'm new to Windows Store programming.

**EDIT**

After going through this [MSDN Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/34fa33d2-36fc-4774-85ee-d617f03a99fc/read-text-file-from-fileopenpicker-vb?forum=winappswithcsharp), I changed the code to this:

```
    StorageFile bookFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/AV/" + bookName + ".txt"));
    Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream ras = await bookFile.OpenReadAsync();
    Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader reader = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader(ras.GetInputStreamAt(0));
    int numOfBytes = (int)ras.Size;
    Byte[] bytes = new Byte[numOfBytes - 1];
    await reader.LoadAsync((uint)numOfBytes);
    reader.ReadBytes(bytes);
    string content = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

This code should have actually worked because when I stepped through it during breakpoint, there was no error. But for some reason I can't fathom, the app doesn't react. When I set a breakpoint and I step into the code, it works (I mean it doesn't break; it does not give me the expected output) but when there is none, it "freezes".

I initially thought it was the size of the file (201 kB) that was taking too long so I changed it to another with a much lesser size (~3 kb) but it was the same. Now I'm thinking it has to do with `async` and `await`. I wish there was a way to do this without using them.

EDIT:
I'm not posting this an answer because I realized the it solved the issue but the question did not contain enough info to get an answer.

The solution was that I didn't use `await` on the method that was calling this method. I would have deleted it but I thought maybe it could be help someone. Thanks to everyone that attempted to solve it.

Comment: In short, it seems that `GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync` returns null and `ReadTestAsync` fails with a warning that you passed a `null` instead of a full path. That's probably because the path you pass to `GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync` doesn't exist

Comment: Actually, I checked it and it was not null. It had a reference to the right file.

Comment: Does `bookname` contain any special characters like `\\`? That happened in [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724718/reading-files-in-windows-phone-8-value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range) and the fix was to use a relative file path to open the file. That worked because special characters must be URL-encoded in an absolute URL path.

Comment: It doesn't. Just short strings. They are actually names of books in the Bible. The line `string bookName = bookN.Replace(" ", "");` only helps to normalise strings such as `1 Samuel` etc.

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace of the exception?

Answer (score 0):

First You can check the property of your file`(Assets/AV/someone.txt)`.

The ***Build Action*** should be ***Content***. But not *Embedded Resource* or others.

If it still error. Then check if the ***file is existed***.

Comment: All the files in the folder have a build action in content