# c# Windows Phone cannot find json file

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1, storagefolder

I'm trying to read data from json file in .NET 4.5 for Windows Phone app. After pressing button the exception appears saying:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
```

My code:

```
public static async Task ReadFile()
{
    StorageFolder local = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;

    if (local != null)
    {
        var file = await local.OpenStreamForReadAsync("bazaDanych.json");

        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            json = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my view of Solution Explorer:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not copying your file to the local storage.

Put your json file under the Assets folder, make sure that it's properties says "Content" and "Copy Always"

On the first launch you should read the json from the package

```
var filename = "Assets/BazaDanych.json";
var sFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(filename);
var fileStream = await sFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
```

And store into the local storage.

There is an example for [Windows 8](http://www.entropyspecialists.com/blog/?p=144) (which is more or less the same)

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724718/reading-files-in-windows-phone-8-value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range).

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this? I'm not sure what do you mean exactly.

Comment: Thanks, it was very helpful, especially the example of code from link that you've pasted. The one important thing that I've changed in my code was  assigning `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` to `StorageFolder`.